# How to support compressed HTTP requests in Asp.Net 4.0 / IIS7?

Tags: asp.net, iis, request, gzip, http-compression

For an ASP.NET 4.0 / IIS7 web app, I would like to support compressed HTTP **requests**. Basically, I would like to support clients that would add `Content-Encoding: gzip` in the request headers, and compress the body accordingly.

Does anyone known how I achieve such a behavior?

Ps: concerning, I have multiple endpoints REST and SOAP, and it feels a better solution to support compression at the HTTP level rather than custom encoders for each endpoint.

Answer (score 5):

For those who might be interested, the implementation is rather straightforward with an `IHttpModule` that simply filters incoming requests.

```
public class GZipDecompressModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += BeginRequest;
    }

    void BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var app = (HttpApplication)sender;

        if ("gzip" == app.Request.Headers["Content-Encoding"])
        {
            app.Request.Filter = new GZipStream(
               app.Request.Filter, CompressionMode.Decompress);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

**Update:** It appears that this approach trigger a problem in WCF, as WCF relies on the original `Content-Length` and not the value obtained after decompressing.

Comment: I was under the impression that it's possible to configure compression at IIS level rather within your hosted application.  However I don't know much about it, just a suggestion google "IIS Compression"

Comment: Classical HTTP compression applies only to **responses**, here that's the **requests** I am trying to compress.

Comment: No, in the end, we decided to re-implement our own HTTP stack :-(

Comment: @JoannesVermorel  Try Wiktor's solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671216/how-do-i-enable-gzip-compression-for-post-upload-requests-to-a-soap-webservice  (noting my bugfixes in my own answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try Wiktor's answer to my similar question here:

[How do I enable GZIP compression for POST (upload) requests to a SOAP WebService on IIS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671216/how-do-i-enable-gzip-compression-for-post-upload-requests-to-a-soap-webservice/16722562?noredirect=1#comment24088280_16722562)

...but please note his implementation on his blog contained a couple of bugs / compatibility issues, so please try my patched version of the HttpCompressionModule class posted on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Although hacky, you can get around WCF using the original `Content-Length` even after the request has been decompressed by setting the private `_contentLength` field in the `HttpRequest` class using reflection.  Using Joannes Vermorel's code:

```
    void BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var app = (HttpApplication)sender;

        if ("gzip" == app.Request.Headers["Content-Encoding"])
        {
            app.Request.Filter = new GZipStream(
                app.Request.Filter, CompressionMode.Decompress);

            // set private _contentLength field with new content length after the request has been decompressed
            var contentLengthProperty = typeof(HttpRequest).GetField("_contentLength", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            contentLengthProperty.SetValue(app.Request, (Int32)app.Request.InputStream.Length);
        }
    }
```