# Implement http compression for post data

Tags: iis, gzip, http-compression

I understand there is little or no standard for implementing gzip compression for data transfers *to* a webserver (as opposed to the standardized option available for the response). But I'm curious what would be the direction to go if I did want to do my own implementation of this this at the server level. Is this something a custom module for IIS could handle?

Comment: I think this post is what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671216/how-do-i-enable-gzip-compression-for-post-upload-requests-to-a-soap-webservice

Comment: appears to be... very good