# Can I change the content of an incoming HTTP request using a HTTP Module?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, filter, gzip

I'm trying to extend my REST service (built using WCF/webHttpBinding) so that clients can upload gzipped data. I'm not sure what the best way to accomplish this but I thought it would be fairly easy by adding a HTTP module which will decompress the data if Content-Encoding for the incoming request is set to gzip.

So I created an class deriving from IHttpModule with the following implementation:

```cs
  private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     var app = (HttpApplication) sender;
     var context = app.Context;

     var contentEncoding = context.Request.Headers["Content-Encoding"];

     if (contentEncoding == "gzip")
     {
        // some debug code:
        var decompressedStream = new GZipStream(context.Request.InputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        decompressedStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
        string msg = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        context.Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        app.Request.Filter = //new TestFilterStream(app.Request.Filter);
                    new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(
                    app.Request.Filter, CompressionMode.Decompress);
     }

  }
```

The issue I'm seeing is that the GZipStream decompression is never actually performed. I've confirmed that the incoming data is in fact gzip'd (the msg-variable contains the proper data). I've also tried creating my own stream class (TestFilterStream) above and assign that to app.Request.Filter and I've confirmed that no members on the stream class is actually called by ASP.NET. So it seems like while it's possible to specify a filter, that filter isn't actually used.

Isn't HttpApplication.Request.Filter actually used?

Comment: have you tried setting `Request.Filter` without your other debug code? It might be that you already read the request stream so it will not apply the filter after that anymore.

Comment: I believe that there's no reason to believe that Request.InputStream is seekable. It probably isn't. Try removing your debug code, it's probably wrong anyway (you may have to close/flush the decompressedStream before it really writes anything into the memory stream).

Comment: Please narrow down the issue, as it is not clear from your question where the actual error occurs and when. Is the problem actually that `GZipStream` does not read the underlying stream? Is `contentEncoding` euqual to `"gzip"`, does the code in the `if` block get called? Have you tried logging the moment this method is called?  Are you even sure your module gets loaded?

Comment: Why not use facilities built in to WCF? You can implement `IDispatchMessageInspector` and unzip the content in the `BeforeSendReply` function. I think you will also need to set `WebBodyFormatMessageProperty` to `Raw`.

Answer (score 2):

I tried setting the Request Filter in two ways:

1. Using a HttpModule
2. Setting it in the start of `Application_BeginRequest()` (Global.asax)

Both with the same results (VS2012 web project + IISExpress):

- If there is no input data (GET request or similar), the `Filter.Read` is not invoked
- In case of a POST with actual data, the filter is executed and the web service gets the filtered data
- Even if I read from the Request.InputStream before the Filter is set, I still get the filter triggered from my service code.

I have no easy way of testing with Gzippet input, so I have not tried if the actual filter works. However, I know it is getting triggered, since I get an error from `GZipStream` while it attempts to look for the input.

Perhaps you are having other HttpModules or Filters that disrupt your input or control flow?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410968/how-to-support-compressed-http-requests-in-asp-net-4-0-iis7) proposes a method similar to yours, but also states the following, which may be causing some side effects (my tests were not using WCF):

> "It appears that this approach trigger a problem in WCF, as WCF relies on the original Content-Length and not the value obtained after decompressing."

Answer (score 0):

I've just done a couple of tests, and my Request.Filter stream is called into, as long as there is a request body and the request body gets read by the http handler. I'm guessing you use either a PUT or a POST, and certainly read the request body, so that shouldn't be a problem.

I suspect Knaģis' comment is correct. Have you tried without the debug code? If I dig into the HttpRequest source, I see a variable _rawContent being written to exactly once; at that same time the request filters are applied. After that the _rawContent value just gets cached, and is never updated (nor reset when a filter is added).

So by calling Request.InputStream in your debug code you are definitely preventing your filter from being applied later on. Reading the Request.Headers collection is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that application itself should bother?
Usually that's handled per configuration of host (IIS). So, basically, you only need to implement custom GZip support, when you host the service yourself.
You can take a look [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingDynamicCompressionGzipDeflateForWCFDataFeedsODataAndOtherCustomServicesInIIS7.aspx)